# prettyPhoto Loading Photos in Reverse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

For some reasons, unknown to me, prettyPhoto is loading images in reverse. It opens the last picture first and then as you can guess, you're given the option to see the previous photo all the way back to the first photo. I've setup prettyPhoto according to the documentation however I'm not getting the desired effect. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a working copy: radiant.dreamhosters.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was kinda odd but I believe I solved it.

**The Problem**
If you look at the link you are clicking to open you gallery you will see the link is to the  last image in your gallery list.
ie the gallery links to  "images/inventory/1/5.jpg" which is your last image

so it takes you to the last image in your gallery because that is what you are clicking, you are not loading the images in reverse you are selecting the last image.

**The Fix**

What I did was give your top image link a css z-index via a css class, this way it is the image you are clicking. Tested this with your code and it worked for me.

like so:

`< style>
.first_img{
    z-index: 10;
}
< /style >`

`< a class="first_img project_hoverPhoto" href="images/inventory/1/1.jpg" rel='prettyPhoto[1]'>`

```
   <a class="project_hoverPhoto" href="images/inventory/1/3.jpg" rel='prettyPhoto[1]'></a>
   <a class="project_hoverPhoto" href="images/inventory/1/4.jpg" rel='prettyPhoto[1]'></a>
   <a class="project_hoverPhoto" href="images/inventory/1/5.jpg" rel='prettyPhoto[1]'></a>

    <img src="images/inventory/1/sm.jpg" alt="" width="280" height="140" /><div id="comments"><a class="comments" rel="#">$9,999.99</a></div>
     <h5>2003 Audi A4 Turbo</h5>
```

Comment: That's pretty darn clever! I wish I had checked this earlier :)

I traced the problem back to position:absolute; and how it was stacking images and creating a Last In First Out scenario, just like you explained. My solution (+mistake) was to simply take out the class tag from the remaining images and it worked as advertised. They shouldn't even be there at the first place :D

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want only on thumbnail per gallery. To achieve this result, the API would be a better choice. Look for the "Public API" documentation under that page: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/

> images = ['images/fullscreen/image1.jpg','images/fullscreen/image2.jpg','images/fullscreen/image3.jpg'];
>       titles = ['Title 1','Title 2','Title 3'];
>       descriptions = ['Description 1','Description 2','Description 3']
>       $.prettyPhoto.open(images,titles,descriptions);

Hope this help :)